# Find all solutions of least squares problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, least-squares

I have the following exercise (this is exercise 4.39 of Fundamentals of Matrix Comuptations - Watkins) :[image]

I am not sure about how to find all the solutions(item e). I think I must use itens c) and d) but I don't see how to do it .
I found the minimal norm solution :

$x_{mn} = A^{\dagger}$ b = $\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  3/35\\
  6/35 
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$

The last column of $V$ is an orthonormal basis for $ \mathcal{N}(A)$ and this column is $\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  -2/\sqrt5\\
  1/\sqrt5 
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$

Any help will be aprecciated

Comment: All solutions to the least-squares problem are found as solutions to $A^TAx = A^Tb$.

Comment: I answered the same question yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3673632/529121

Comment: @Jan So based on your answer the set of all solutions is given by {$ x_{nm} + z$} where z can be $(-2 , 1)^T$ for example . Is that right?

Comment: Yes, but I did not checked the numbers. If you found that the vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (-2, 1)$ spans the kernel of $A$, you can choose $z$ as $(-2, 1)^\intercal$ and write the solution set as you said.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jan

Comment: You're welcome. If you want, I can answer your question using the result you have given. Just tell me.

Comment: I would appreciate it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672241/fundamentals-of-matrix-computations-watkins-exercise-4-3-9e-svd?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer I explained that the set of all solutions of the least-squares problem can be written as $\{x_{\text{mn}} + z : z \in \mathcal{N}(A) \}$. Here, $x_{\text{mn}} = A^+ b$ is the minimum-norm solution and $\mathcal{N}(A)$ is the kernel of $A$.

You were able to calculate $x_{\text{mn}} = \frac{1}{35}(3, 6)$ and you obtained that the vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (-2, 1)$ spans the kernel of $A$. Therefore, the desired solution set is

$$\{x_{\text{mn}} + z : z \in \mathcal{N}(A) \} = \{(3/35, 6/35) + t ( -2, 1) : t \in \mathbb{R} \}.$$